# ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

Имеется проект, обычное консольное приложение. Хочу добавить Empty Code First Model как на картинке, но у меня только 2 первых пункта. Что нужно обновить в VS, чтобы появились 2 последних пункта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Entity FrameWork 6. Microsoft NET Framework в установке и удалении программ 4.6.1, 4.8 есть и 4.5.